# Reap and Sow From NDSolve solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I want to get the answer of my `NDSolve` in the form of table (the value of each `x` and `y`). Let's say that I want to copy this result into the excel or microsoft word and then put it in the appendix or make a chart from it.

I tried to use `Reap` and `Sow` function in order to do this.

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Reap[Sow[s,{x,0,30}]
```

However, instead of giving me a number `(x,y)`, it gives me an interpolation function.
Anyone has an idea how to get `x` and `y` from this type of equation?

Comment: does this give what you need: `f = y /. s // First; Table[{k, f[k]}, {k, 0, 30, .5}]`?

Comment: Please confess you were joking about using Excel, please

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the usage of `Sow` in the question is incorrect. The second argument of `Sow` is a tag to identify the object for later use, not a range specification as seems to be implied in `{x, 0, 30}`. In fact because of this error I think the question is probably not going to help anyone looking for `Reap` and `Sow`...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the sampling points used internally, you can extract the properties of the `InterpolatingFunction[]` object like so:

```
s = y /. First @ NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}];

Short[pts = Transpose[Append[s["Coordinates"], s["ValuesOnGrid"]]], 10]
   {{0., 1.}, {0.00017069, 1.00009}, {0.00034138, 1.00018}, {0.00068276, 1.00037},
    {0.00102414, 1.00055}, {0.00136552, 1.00074}, {0.00477932, 1.00257},
    {0.00819312, 1.00439}, {0.0116069, 1.0062}, {0.0150207, 1.008},
    <<318>>, {28.7031, 0.0334113}, {28.8529, 0.0293757}, {29.0026, .0261519},
    {29.1524, 0.0236348}, {29.3022, 0.0217328}, {29.4519, 0.0203714}, {29.6017, 0.0194947},
    {29.7515, 0.0190656}, {29.8757, 0.019036}, {30., 0.0193018}}
```

If you need **regularly spaced** points, however, then you do what kguler says:

```
Table[{x // N, s[x]}, {x, 0, 30, 1/2}]
   {{0., 1.}, {0.5, 1.12111}, {1., 0.991387}, {1.5, 0.761165}, {2., 0.528358},
    {2.5, 0.338378}, {3., 0.206604}, {3.5, 0.128089}, {4., 0.0880718}, {4.5, 0.0731787},
    {5., 0.0773121}, {5.5, 0.103268}, {6., 0.16258}, {6.5, 0.264004}, {7., 0.37356},
    {7.5, 0.412578}, {8., 0.358411}, {8.5, 0.259648}, {9., 0.166528}, {9.5, 0.10145},
    {10., 0.064349}, {10.5, 0.0469302}, {11., 0.0424986}, {11.5, 0.0491715},
    {12., 0.0704073}, {12.5, 0.113928}, {13., 0.181682}, {13.5, 0.246869}, {14., 0.262814},
    {14.5, 0.22087}, {15., 0.154679}, {15.5, 0.0968125}, {16., 0.059186}, {16.5, 0.0392205},
    {17., 0.0310103}, {17.5, 0.0310352}, {18., 0.0394376}, {18.5, 0.0600941},
    {19., 0.0984724}, {19.5, 0.15096}, {20., 0.191026}, {20.5, 0.188813}, {21., 0.148847},
    {21.5,0.0993506}, {22., 0.060922}, {22.5, 0.0379967}, {23., 0.0268224},
    {23.5, 0.0233117}, {24., 0.025871}, {24.5, 0.0358221}, {25., 0.057114},
    {25.5, 0.0927678}, {26., 0.133994}, {26.5, 0.155512}, {27., 0.141107}, {27.5, 0.103738},
    {28., 0.0662557}, {28.5, 0.040382}, {29., 0.0262021}, {29.5, 0.0200394},
    {30., 0.0193018}}
```