# Grid for NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

i want to get the output of `NDSolve` in the form of a table/grid that can be exported to .xls/.csv.

```
NDSolve[x'[t]==Exp[t], y'[t]==cos[t], x[0]=0, y[0]=1,{x[t],y[t]},{t,0,10}]
```

I am expecting an output in the form of 12(rows)x3(columns) Table where the first row has the following entries:
t, x(t), y(t).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19344/reap-and-sow-from-ndsolve-solution

Answer (score 1):

> 12(rows)x3(columns) Table where the first row has the following
>   entries: t, x(t), y(t).

```
ClearAll[x, y, t];
ode1 = x'[t] == Exp[t];
ode2 = y'[t] == Cos[t];
ic   = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1};
sol  = First@DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t];
data = Table[{t, x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, Subdivide[10, 11]}];
N[data] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But how do I export a Matrix as .xls/.CSV file.

Comment: @PuneethV, just use `Export["file.csv", N@data, "CSV"]`.